# FFMpeg Simply/Fast convert video file not working with any video

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

I'm using the fast convert mkv to mp4 ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy new.mp4
```

But is not working with any mkv file, when trying to run it, the file is to small about 1mb and getting this error. I know that will work if I won't use copy and add a library but this will take long time

```
    Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: -83 >= -83
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, one of the streams has irregularities in its timestamps, so let FFmpeg's Matroska muxer sort it out.

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts+genpts -i test.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy new.mkv
```

then mux that to MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i new.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy new.mp4
```

Comment: It worked for the first 3 but then again same error why :/

Comment: I've altered the first cmd in my answer.

Comment: The same again but file is upto 1mb more.

Comment: Try with `-fflags +igndts+genpts+discardcorrupt`. If no, paste the full console output.

Comment: You want all the console output?

Comment: Yes. Add `-report`. It will make a log file. You can paste it to pastebin and link it here.

Comment: That's just the input details. Show the report from running the copy command.

Comment: Can't do it with report

Comment: Saying Missing argument for option report

Comment: ffmpeg -fflags +igndts+genpts+discardcorrupt -i video.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy new.mkv -report

Comment: What's your ffmpeg version?

Comment: 0.8.17-4:0.8.17 ubuntu.

Comment: I'm on shared hosting so can't udpated it on my own asked for update thought this one was latest